# 3 Dots after a text that not fit in to the textview size

Tags: android-layout, android

I have this piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100sp"          
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/click"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="30sp"               
       android:text="Enter the text right over here"
       android:textSize="25sp"  
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textStyle="bold"     
       android:onClick="onClick"                     
       android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the "Enter the text right over here" text to be written as "Enter the text right..."
(because the text exceeds the width defined.

How can I create that functionallity ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set your textview as below:

```
<TextView 
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:singleLine="true"

       android:id="@+id/click"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="30sp"               
       android:text="Enter the text right over here"
       android:textSize="25sp"  
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textStyle="bold"     
       android:onClick="onClick"                     
       android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Also don't be shaded by the fact that `singleLine` is deprecated and you should use `maxLines`. With `maxLines="1"` and `ellipsize="end"` you'll get the whole line replaced with `"..."`

Answer (score 2):

Deprecated:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

In Use:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) property.